java.lang.ClassCastException when using iText 2.2 to stamp data into a PDF
I am encountering a java.lang.ClassCastException in my application when using iText 2.2 to sign and stamp certain PDF documents. The error occurs intermittently when processing PDFs that include tables and have more than 4 pages. After rebooting the Tomcat server where the app is deployed, it works again. The relevant part of the stack trace is as follows:
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDictionary cannot be cast to com.lowagie.text.pdf.PRIndirectReference
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader.eliminateSharedStreams(PdfReader.java:2233) ~[itext-2.2.jar:?]
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(PdfReader.java:521) ~[itext-2.2.jar:?]
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:184) ~[itext-2.2.jar:?]
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:173) ~[itext-2.2.jar:?]
    ...

We are using iText 2.2 to stamp some data on PDF files. In some of these documents, which include tables and more than 4 pages, intermittent errors occur that we cannot explain. Any insights on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Cannot reproduce the error even with the same PDF file. Tomcat server reboot makes it work again.
I expect to work with any PDF without any problem.

There is no official iText 2.2. After 2.1.7 there was an inofficial 4.2 and then 5.x. So which version does your 2.2 correspond to, and which changes were applied? If your iText variant essentially is a 2.1.7, then there is an error in the PDF processed by that PdfReader, the Contents array of some page contains a direct object while only streams are allowed which cannot be direct. "Cannot reproduce the error even with the same PDF file." - that is weird. Do you in your code only open the input PDFs in PdfReaders or also PDFs generated by your code?

In addition to what @mkl said, what is the running environment? Version of Tomcat, JDK? Also [edit] the question and add a [mre]. Let others understand the code and try to reproduce. Having said that, if this a bug of a fork of itext based on a very old version (2.1.7 was released in 2009) then the bug should be fixed by the fork maintainers. There is nothing to be done about that in [so].
